# How To Divide Gotten Data from A Datatable And Bind Some Of Them To Headertemplate of Datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

May be the subject is complicated, so I'll try to explain:

I get some data from database which some of them has TypeId=1 and some has TypeId=2. I want to take data which TypeId=1 to header template and TypeId=2 to itemtemplate in the Datalist control.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) to get a subset of the data in a DataTable and then bind that to the DataList for the item content, but you'll have to manually insert the data into the heading by attaching to the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound(VS.80).aspx) event and looking for the ListItemType of Header.